How does Javascript know that it is an event even with different name?
I think everybody who once coded in Javascript knows the events. As an example I have:


document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  console.log(event);
});



But my head still doesn't get it: How does the function knows that it has to give back, because I didn't defint it anywhere. Is it just, that the "addEventListener" says that there hast du be an event in the function, no matter the name or is it about the "keypress"?

I forgot: I tried to name it "pastry" and it still worked of course.. but why^^'

It's just a function parameter, you can name it anything you want (or even omit it and use arguments, or destructuring, or rest parameters, or …). The function will be called with an event object as the argument, just a normal function call. "how does the function then knows, that it has to listen to the events" - the function knows nothing. It's addEventListener that sets up the listening.

You can call it whatever you like, it's just a normal function parameter. event or e are just naming conventions

You can name like you want. The caller doesn't need to know how a function names its parameters. It is like that with all functions.

Try it: document.addEventListener("keydown", function(pastry) {   console.log(pastry.code); });

Just a mid-pendantic note that might bring confusion, but window.event is actually a thing, and in most cases it will be the same as your callback's first argument, but not in all (e.g. you could await in your callback). So calling your own event parameter event might in some cases be confusing, though to be fair using the global window.event is probably what's the most confusing.

Unfortunately still no one could answer my question.


Is it just, that the "addEventListener" says that there hast du be an event in the function, no matter the name?

"addEventListener" provides the event to the function, by means of a regular function call.
Function parameters in JavaScript are usually positional, not name-based. So it doesn't matter what name the called function uses; addEventListener only cares that it needs to pass the event as parameter #1, and the function will receive it as parameter #1. The "inside" and "outside" variable names might happen to match, or they might not.
For example, when you have function greet(name) and function greet(pancake), an outside caller cannot distinguish between the two: it just does greet("Fred") – it does not specify the name by greet(name="Fred") or anything like that.
(Some other programming languages do have named parameters – e.g. Python does.)
Since your event callback is still a regular function (and is called like a regular function), the same applies to its parameters.
function exampleCaller(name, callback) {
    let text = "Hello, " + name + "!";
    let result = callback(text); // ⇐
}

exampleCaller("Fred", function(message) {
    console.log(`Was called with message "${message}"`);
});

exampleCaller("Fred", function(greeting) {
    console.log(`Was called with parameter: ${greeting}`);
});


That's exactly what i mean in your code: I didn't define what is in the parameter "event" like your "callback" parameter where you defined "text" -> let result = callback(text);

Right, but it's the job of addEventListener to define that. The exampleCaller() function in my example was meant to stand in for addEventListener(), not for your code.

The function you provide to addEventListener is a callback with a specific signature. From that link:

the callback accepts a single parameter: an object based on Event describing the event that has occurred

So, the parameter name is not relevant (it can be anything from e to haveYourCakeAndEatIt). The type of the parameter is relevant: it is always an Event.
It works somewhat the same as when you create a function with a factory:


const x = doSomethingWithACallbackFactory();
const myCallback = whatCanWeDoWithMyNumber =>
  console.log(`My rocking number is ${whatCanWeDoWithMyNumber}`)

x.doStuff(42, myCallback);
x.doStuff(`forty-two`, myCallback);

function doSomethingWithACallbackFactory() {
  return {
    doStuff(nr, callback) {
      if (nr.constructor !== Number) {
        throw new TypeError(`we need a number here, not [${nr}]!`);
      }

      return callback(nr);
    },
  }
}




But how does the function knows it is an Event and not just something else? I didn't define what Event actually should do. So how does Javascript know?

@Kasuna89 The function is not typed, there is no type declaration and no difference at runtime. Why it is relevant is only for the programmer who implements the function: if they assumed the wrong type, their code will break.

@Kasuna89 Javascript 'knows' nothing. It is the way the function addEventListener is programmed in the js engine.

The second parameter of addEventListener is a function of a specific kind: a function that accepts a parameter of type Event (really of type Object with some fields)
Maybe this is more clear:


document.addEventListener("keydown", theEventHandlingFunction);


function theEventHandlingFunction(aParameterOfTypeEvent) {
    console.log(aParameterOfTypeEvent.code);
}



A function is a closed piece of script that executes and returns some value, it can receive values to process, called parameters. Parameters can have any name, the name is just a placeholder, a way to identify the value.
In JavasScript you can pass a whole function as parameter and it can be called later. In your example you passed to addEventListener an anonymous function, a function with no name, defined just for the porpouse: "call my function when an event occurs".
In my example I gave that same function a name and a clear definition.
It needs one parameter and, whatever the name of that parameter, it is expected to be an object (group of key value things) with some special fields like "code", "target", etc that you can use.

A JavaScript function is an object of type Function. When you create an anonymous function like that, you are in fact creating a new Function object, with parameters and a body. Then, you provide this object as a parameter to the document.addEventListener function, which in turn provides a value to the first parameter of your function, regardless of the parameter name, and executes it. Your function doesn't know anything about document.addEventListener (although you can get its name in your function), it just runs with the value it was provided.

The addEventListener() is a function that takes two parameters: a string indicating the type of event to listen to, and a listener, which is an object that will receive the event.
The name of the listener does not matter and can be a variable to store the event, but it is most common to use a function.
In your example, "event" is the parameter of the function identified as the listener, the parameter of the function (if you provide one) will contain the event and can be named as you please (such as "pastry" in your example).
You can learn more about the addEventListener() on the mozilla documentation
